# XMPP Client incompabilities

Tags: java, client, xmpp, instant-messaging

I'm currently working on a project that is building a java-based desktop application to interface with a website. We want to incorporate IM capabilities, so we decided to use XMPP.

The problem is our application has other features, and anyone using another client to connect to our XMPP server will cause problems with our website (e.g. our client will be able to send our messages with a certain message type that the user won't be able to use, but with another client they could send those message types).

Is there anyone to either allow only our client to access the XMPP server or prevent other clients from using certain features? I know this is against the idea of open standards, but we don't want to build a proprietary IM solution from scratch.

Comment: Please clarify: "our client will be able to send our messages with a certain message type that the user won't be able to use, but with another client they could send those message types)."  Do you mean that your server won't be able to handle standard clients, or that your clients won't work with standard servers? I'm guessing the former, but if that's the case, it's not obvious *why* interoperability would be a problem.

Comment: Essentially, we want to be able to use XMPP to send out some kind of status message (different from normal IM status changes) that comes from a different feature of our application (e.g. it monitors something then sends out a status message when it goes off). Our client will be able to send and receive these messages using a different message type than the standard chat one, but another client wouldn't.

We don't have a problem with this being proprietary, but the XMPP features are really nice and I'd rather use something like the Smack API and run an XMPP server than do all of that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* building a proprietary solution, it just might not be completely from scratch, and that's not necessarily a bad thing.  But please don't call it a XMPP service unless you are going to support XMPP clients. You will get the same reaction as you get with a "web site" that requires your proprietary browser.

For features that can be negotiated, look at [Feature Negotiation](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0020.html) and you might be able to get away with saying your server doesn't have a specific feature to other clients, but secretly supporting it in your own.  That won't actually block something from being attempted, so it's pretty poor solution.

You can get instant messaging capabilities without building a desktop application (with all of the platform support headaches that entails).  Consider [Orbited](http://orbited.org/) which can give you the instant messaging interactivity your looking for and would make it much easier to integrate on the server.

And just as a side point, there shouldn't be any messages that cause problems with your web site, any more than there could be a URL that causes it problems, or a query combination, etc.

Comment: We need the desktop application because of the other features. XMPP is so easy to use, that I'd rather just run an XMPP server and use the Smack API. The problem is I DON'T want to call it an XMPP service, and I don't want other XMPP clients to work, but I don't see any way to ignore clients that aren't ours.

I guess the equivalent would be something like Steam, where you have an IM program on top of all the other stuff Steam does (managing games, their store, etc). We don't want someone to be able to just write their own IM client because we want them to run our client for everything else.

Comment: Humm.  How about hijacking the connection authentication?  Maybe using a separate authentication service that returns some token you can pass along to the connection API.  Blocks other clients from connecting because they can't do the same dance.  Kinda ugly maybe.

Comment: @Joel - you may be interested in the pubsub stuff I mentioned.  You can create a whitelist of users that can access a given node to give you the security you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of all your requirements, but it sounds like you could probably use the pubsub or pep features of XMPP.  These are extensions to XMPP that allow you to create specialized payloads that can be accessed on a user to user level (Personal Eventing Protocol XEP-0163).  If it is simply a general notification to everyone who is interested, then PubSub (XEP-0060) may be what you want.

These protocols allow for securing access to the pubsub nodes and will not get affected by the standard chat messages, as they are a different protocol.